# Kubernetes Redis BigQuery Real time tweets not getting through

Tags: twitter, redis, google-bigquery, kubernetes, real-time-data

I am new to the google cloud and cloud architecture so excuse my ignorance.

I am trying to run the real time data analysis tutorial using Kubernetes, Redis and BigQuery.

I have followed the tutorial to the letter and once I've spun up the required environments I am not getting any tweets coming through to the BigQuery tables.

Can anyone recommend how to troubleshoot the bottleneck in the pipeline? Is there anyway to 'ping' to see if each service is connected?

Open to any suggestions.

Many thanks,

john

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the [application troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/application-troubleshooting.md)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial that you are following?

Comment: I am following the following tutorial from Google: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time/kubernetes-redis-bigquery